# How to make chrome extension hotkey work for ALL tabs?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, hotkeys

I'm using this code in the contents script to implement a hotkey in my Chrome Extension:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  var modifier = event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey;
  if (modifier && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 80) {
    // stuff happens here
  }
});
```

Is there any way to make this hotkey work on Chrome tabs like the New Tab, Extensions, Settings etc. without using NPAPI?

Comment: I believe that's impossible. That's a good thing in fact - if you install an extension and it is then able to hijack the Extensions page, it can change all kinds of settings, or prevent you from uninstalling the extension etc.

Comment: Baaa! But I don't want to DO anything on these pages except maybe send requests to the background script. Is there really no way for extensions to register their own little hotkeys?

Comment: Honestly, I think these special pages are isolated and protected. But perhaps someone else can come up with a solution.

Comment: You should make a request for implementation of hotkeys API on http://new.crbug.com, I would definitively support that.

Comment: Implementing general-purpose keyboard shortcuts for extensions is covered http://crbug.com/27702. It's being actively worked on, but until it's finished, there's no mechanism for creating shortcuts that work when the user is actively using chrome://* pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new chrome.experimental.keybinding api and make your hotkey gobal http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.keybinding.html